# HTC Desire - Problem writing to /system

Tags: htc-desire

I have an HTC Desire HD Android device. I rooted it with SuperOneClick. I get a # prompt in terminal. adb remount fails. I'm able to remount /system with

```
mount -o rw,remount /dev/block/mmcblk0p25 /system
```

I can now make changes to /system.

The problem is that my changes are erased when I reboot the phone. This is true even if I create a small dummy file, e.g. derf.txt

Also any new apps that I install go in /data/app while the pre-installed apps are in /system/app.

Output of mount is:

```
mount
rootfs / rootfs ro,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p25 /system ext3 rw,relatime,errors=continue,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p26 /data ext3 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,data=o
rdered 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p27 /cache ext3 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,data=
ordered 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p28 /devlog ext3 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,data
=ordered 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /app-cache tmpfs rw,relatime,size=8192k,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
/data/d /data/d debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/block/vold/179:33 /mnt/sdcard vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,
uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharse
t=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/block/vold/179:33 /mnt/secure/asec vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,rela
time,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,ioc
harset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure tmpfs ro,relatime,size=0k,mode=000 0 0
#
```

Has anyone seen this? Can you explain why my changes get wiped out when I reboot the phone?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sounds like its temporary rooted for the duration of handset on, and when reboot, changes are lost.

Comment: have to agree with @t0mm13b. try flashing a rooted kernel instead

Comment: I really want to avoid having to flash a new kernel.

Comment: This actually sounds to me like your bootloader is locked. Did you use any kind of S-OFF tool after rooting? I don't think SuperOneClick does that for you.

Comment: @user1491924 why? Rooting does not necessarily imply voiding the warranty, rather more so, unlocking the bootloader does. If that's what your suggestively implying as to why you have it temporarily rooted. :)

Comment: I think you'll find that manufacturers and carriers will tell you rooting voids your warranty :P.  That said I agree with eldarerathis, it sounds like the bootloader is locked and a kernel won't do anything.  `Also any new apps that I install go in /data/app while the pre-installed apps are in /system/app.` <-- completely normal.

Comment: Thank you. I used gfree to change to S-OFF and now it persists the changes :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
mount -o rw,remount /dev/block/mmcblk0p25 /system
```

try

```
mount -o rw,remount /system
```

Comment: This gives an error `mount -o rw,remount /system`
`Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory`

Comment: is this in adb or a device terminal, out of curiosity?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (was) that HTC apply a software write protection to `mmc` partitions, some workaround exist ([wp_mod.ko](https://github.com/flar2/wp_mod)) but being a kernel module isn't handy.

ps: on old HTC 2.3.x the corrent syntax for `mount` need both the device and the mount point.